# Сложности с «наверное»

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить дилемму! Интересует выделение запятыми слова *наверное*.

«И тут, в самом конце этого чудовищного представления, порыв ветра принёс откуда-то, наверное, из чьего-то разрушенного очага, груду горящих углей».

Это слово, при выделении запятыми, может создать путаницу у читателя, — к какой части предложения оно будет отнесено:

*порыв ветра принёс откуда-то, наверное*, и *наверное, из чьего-то разрушенного очага*?

Что можно тут сделать? Дробить предложение нежелательно в принципе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно:

*И тут, в самом конце этого чудовищного представления, порыв ветра принёс откуда-то, **наверное из чьего-то разрушенного очага,** груду горящих углей.*

См.:

> [**§ 93.**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126#pp126) Если вводное слово или вводное сочетание слов стоит в
>   начале или в конце обособленного члена предложения, то оно не
>   отделяется от него знаком препинания,
>
> т. е. **запятые выделяют член предложения вместе с вводным словом**...